# Birthday campaign with Mobile connect(sms)

Tags: marketing-cloud, filters, mobileconnect, automationstudio

My team was working on a SMS birthday campaign which expected to use Mobile Connect and the Automation studio send out daily.
So far we successfully fire the event hence the data extension in Email could import as a list in Mobile connect by import definitions.

But the problem is when I try to set up a Birthday campaign, I found the filter is different from the email's one.

**Email data extension filter**
[image: email extension filter]

**Mobile connect filter**
[image: sms filter]

In email, you may use anniversary as the condition, and when it =today to filter the date of birth while in mobile connect the filter condition is not found.

We are expecting to filter out birthday=today in mobile connect and run in automation daily after it is set up.
But at the moment seems we can only manually update the date filter daily to make sure we have the correct audience list in sms send out. Automation studio can not set up as refresh the list and schedule send out sms.

We have tried to filter on the email side(extension) first, but mobile connect seems only able to recognize standard extension ONLY but not filtered extension.

Please let us know if there is anyone who knows the solution or come across the situation before.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i'm aware, Salesforce recognizes Today() /with or without parenthesis/ as a usable variable, at least for reports. So it might work out for you there